Taylor expansion and analyticity on Banach spaces
I know there is a notion of Taylor series for functions on Banach spaces. If $X$ and $Y$ are real or complex Banach spaces and $f: X \to Y$, this means that:
$$f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^{2} + \cdots \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Here, of course, I am assuming that $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ at $x=0$. The derivatives are Fréchet derivatives, and the notation is explained on  this MSE question. Let me just mention that, in my terminology, if a function has a Taylor expansion at $x$ which converges to $f(x)$ then it is called analytic on $x$.
My question is not about this Taylor series, but instead about a different version of a Taylor expansion. More specifically, about the following one:
$$f(\lambda x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}\bigg{(}\frac{\partial^{k}f(\lambda_{1}x_{1}+\cdots +\lambda_{n}x_{n})}{\partial \lambda_{1}\cdots \partial  \lambda_{k}}\bigg{)}\bigg{|}_{\lambda_{1} = \cdots = \lambda_{k} = 0},\tag{2}\label{2}$$
where the $\lambda$'s are all real/complex parameters and I used the notation $x_{1},...,x_{k}$ just for convenience, but these are all copies of $x$.
Regarding this second Taylor series, I have two related questions.
Q1: What is the relation between the second (\ref{2}) and the first (\ref{1}) Taylor expansion? Is the second one equivalent to the first one when $\lambda = 1$? Is it standard to define a function to be analytic on $x$ by requiring that the second Taylor expansion exists and converges fo $f(x)$?
Q2: If I have a sequence $\{f_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of functions such that their Taylor series (\ref{2}) converge to $f$ everywhere inside a domain, say $\Omega \subset X$. Can something be said of the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_{n}(x)$, for $x \in \Omega$ fixed? Is there any known criteria for the existence of this limit?

@jd27 $x^2$ is short-hand notation for the tuple $(x,x)$ etc (as mentioned in the link). But yea the $x_1$ doesn’t make sense to me.

Thanks for the comments. In fact, I used the notation $x_{1},...,x_{k}$, but this is just for notation convenience. In other words, the points $x_{1},...,x_{k}$ are just copies of $x$.

@peek-a-boo ahh, my bad. I only read the first paragraph of the linked post. Should have read the second one as well. So e.g. $f^{\prime \prime} (0) x^2$ is really just shorthand for $f^{\prime \prime} (0) (x,x)$ which i guess makes perfect sense.

In the sum in formula (2) is there supposed to be $\lambda_1 x + \cdots + \lambda_k x$ instead of $\lambda_1 x_1 + \cdots \lambda_n x_n$? In  that case a relation between the two formulas might be deduced by using the chain rule when evaluating the terms in formula (2)?

Also we can exploit that $x \in X$ is fixed and so we are really looking at the function $\mathbb{K} \ni \lambda \mapsto f(\lambda x) \in Y$ if i understand correctly.

@jd27 exactly, this is correct! Thanks for the comment! I only used different names $x_{1},...,x_{k}$ to couple with the $\lambda$'s in a more natural way.
